# Good as or as good as

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, grammaticality

1.**He is good as I am.**

2.**He is as good as I am.**

What is the difference between these two? Do they mean the same?
I think 1 means that I'm good and he is also good. 2 means that we both are good and his quantity of goodness is equal to that of mine. Am I thinking right?

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking correctly, but there's a twist: the nuance of being "good" is that it applies to one's *nature* or *character*, not one's *ability.*

Saying "as good as" would usually be understood to address ability; whereas in your first sentence, it is the character of the person in focus.

**The natural implications are these:**

1.He is good as I am. (We are both good.)

2.He is as good as I am. (We are equally capable.)

Comment: 'Good' can mean 'capable', 'suitable', 'morally admirable' in both cases. 'I am as good as Saint Peter' said my very holy (and vey vain) friend.

Answer (score -1):

Sentence (1) is incorrect. If you wanted it to mean "I'm good and he is also good," you would need to say:

> He is good, as **am I.**

Comment: 'He is good, as I am' is fine, if a little vain.

Comment: Typically subject-auxiliary inversion is required in elliptical expressions after *as*.

Comment: Who says that? He is happy, as I am, to greet our new King! (invented in haste, I am not a royalist)